# How to get "i am 11 years old" from "i am 11 years old 1111111111" using regular expression?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

How to get "i am 11 years old" from "i am 11 years old 1111111111"  using regular expression?

I have been thinking so long...

Update:
come up with a regular expression which would replace 11 to eleven and the test string given to them was "i am 11 years old 1111111111". Now the extra 1111111111 at the end was just a trick to see if their regular expressions was correct. If the regular expression was correct the outcome should be "i am eleven years old 1111111111".

Comment: Why do you *have* to use a regular expression here?

Comment: Your input doesn't appear to be very *regular*

Comment: what thoughts have you had? Are you doing this to learn about regular expression? If not there are easier ways.

Comment: Replace ` 1111111111` from the string. Seriously though, you need to explain how your input might look like. Giving just one example without an explanation is not enough, there are few mind readers roaming SO.

Comment: I don't see any logical patterns here. Are there always going to be 1s or integers after 'i am 11 years old'? Need more information...

Comment: Maybe you want to remove repeating characters from the end, in case your users entered junk: `(.)\1{3,}$`

Comment: `Regex my_precise_regex=new Regex("i am 11 years old");`

Comment: @DEN How on earth are you managing to get the string "i am 11 years old 1111111111". You should explain the context better.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
i am \d\d years old
```

Comment: How about young kids and really old folk?

Comment: @Thilo: `i am \d{1,3} years old` should do it

Comment: What about a very young baby who is particular about his grammar - "I am 1 year old."

Comment: @JP19: a 1 year old baby can't write yet ;)

Comment: @acme: I have seen Twitter messages that are supposed to be from babies ;) Some even have their own website!

Comment: @Felix: to be fair, though: were they particular about their grammar?

Answer (score 1):

If andrew and DEN are the same person, this will do the "**specific**" job:

```
s/\b11\b/eleven/
```

Comment: me and andrew is not same people, he asked me the question and i posted it up. since everyone is not clear about the question, so i asked andrew to post up the question to make it clear :)